# Cat fell from window on his side

Tags: cats, health, injury

As the title suggests, my cat fell from a window on his side.

It's two stories high and there're decorative pebbles beneath with a few plants. His behaviour hasn't changed besides that when he lies he either repositions his left leg (He fell on his left, I think) or just rises to his feet and walk away. I checked his gums, and they don't appear abnormal.

I'm afraid he may have some internal damage. What should I do?

Comment: take your cat to the vet,i do not know what else you can do if it had been yourself having a fall and thinking you might have broken someting had you posted it on the net or gone to a doctor?.

Comment: I addressed this badly. I'm consulting an emergency vet asap tomorrow, looking for advice on handling currently.

Comment: just keep an eye on your cat and make sure she/he have water and food where it rest so your cat do not need to move a lot,if there is some internal injury it might take some time before your cat show signs of this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have the existing question [Should I take my cat to the vet after a big fall/jump?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/11135) as indicated in one of the answers there, cats mostly land on their feet automatically.

If you cat fell and landed on it's side, there is very possibly something going on prior to the fall.  In other words you should be concerned that he fell and landed on his side instead of his feet, you should be more concerned about what caused him to not land on his feet.

Tomorrow is Saturday, if an emergency vet visit on Saturday is an option, check to see if there is 24 hour vet in your area, and go now.